# plank/laravel-mediable - Deletion vs detachment of media when Mediable entities deleted

Tags: php, laravel

When a model with the Mediable trait is deleted, all references to associated Media are automatically purged from the Mediables table by virtue of a event listener.  Fine.  But this does not delete the associated Media entries, or the files on disk that went with those media.  I can understand that this is in part by design: those Media entries might also be associated with other entities.

But in this context, a Media item will only be attached to one item at a time, and if the item disappears, the Media item and its associated files should go with it.

Currently, I solve this by registering a deleting() listener on the model and looping through any attached media, detaching it, and then deleting it, one by one.

Is this the recommended approach or have I missed some implementation detail in laravel-media that would take care of this housecleaning automatically when the number of references to a given Media are exhausted?

```
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::deleting(function (self $model) {
            $mediabytag = $model->getAllMediaByTag();
            if ($mediabytag) {
                foreach ($mediabytag as $tag => $medias) {
                    foreach ($medias as $m) {
                        $model->detachMedia($m);
                        $m->delete();
                    }
                }
          }
        });
    }
```

**Update:** As I understand it, Mediable sets the relationship up as a polymorphic many-to-many:

```
    /**
     * Relationship for all attached media.
     * @return MorphToMany
     */
    public function media(): MorphToMany
    {
        return $this
            ->morphToMany(
                config('mediable.model'),
                'mediable',
                config('mediable.mediables_table', 'mediables')
            )
            ->withPivot('tag', 'order')
            ->orderBy('order');
    }
```

Comment: is it one to many relationship?

Comment: @MikeRoss, no, if I understand correctly, the Mediable trait sets it up as a polymorphic many-to-many relationship.  (See updated post above.)